# Executing anonymous block (pl/sql) returns numeric value

Tags: plsql, dbms-output

I am a beginner in oracle sql. I want to test out a simple anonymous block as following from sql plus in expecting "foo" but instead numeric value "2" is returned. I am trying to understand why.

```
set serveroutput on size 20000;
begin 
  dbms_output.put_line('foo'); 
end; 
/
```

Comment: Are you sure you typed everything in SQLPLus, including the /?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably missed the final `/`; besides, the procudere you want to call is `put_line` ( with the underscore).

```
SQL> set serveroutput on size 20000;
SQL> begin
  2    dbms_output.put_line('foo');
  3  end;
  4  /
foo

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```